# account issues - invoke file through ssrs hyperlink

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

i have a hyperlink in one of the columns (in tablix) in an ssrs report which points to some server where a dump of documents reside..the hyperlink is appended with a doc_id which helps locate that doc and to invoke it from that server..now this works fine if the ssrs report runs with the current windows logged in user and when the same logged in user is also set up beforehand on that document server where the ssrs hyperlink points to..and this was in dev env..

going ahead in a controlled env, there would only be one system a/c which will be set up on that doc server and regardless of who the logged in windows user is who runs the report; access to the docs on that doc server will only be given to that sys a/c..so i passed this same sys a/c (which is set up on that doc server) in the data source in report mgr --> credentials stored securely in report server..and thought that these credentials will be 
picked while navigating to that doc server and the doc would be opened..but this doesn't seem to happen and it doesn't invoke the document...says invalid credentials..so i think it's picking my logged in credentials here and not the ones of the sys a/c that i entered in data source...(pls note here, the doc server url doesn't contain the report server / report manager url components..it's a different url and is used to only open the doc..so i don't think i can pass user credentials to that url like &dsu:Datasourcename=username&dsp:Datasourcename=password..may be i am wrong and i can pass? but don't think that's secure even if it's an option?)

alternatively, i thought this could be achieved by changing the execution account to this system a/c, under reporting services config mgr..but then we only have ssrs client tools installed..so can't change server settings..and just for this one requirement, nobody would accept my request to change the execution account...also don't know if changing exec account is even a solution for this?

i hope the question is clear..please give some work arounds..i'm stumped and not getting required help anywhere..

note: as another work around, i asked if a group can be set up on that doc server..and when all the users accessing the report are added to the group, they can open the doc after navigating from ssrs report...but the idea giving access to a group was rejected...they can only give access to this sys a/c...